# How do I reinstall Magento 2.1, but keep all my CMS Pages, Blocks, Product Data?

Tags: magento-2.1, product, cms, installation

I have built my entire site on a Magento 2.1.2 installation w/ sample data.  Using an extension and some manual labor, I was able to delete most of the sample data (categories, pages, products), but as stated in the docs, it does not clear the database completely.

In the docs it also says **NOT TO DO ANY DEVELOPMENT** with sample data installed...but due to time constraints and having to "learn Magento overnight", I went forward.

Now, my O.C.D. is kicking in and I want a clean install.  With all the changes coming, I'm worried that the old installation with the sample data will clog my current site if I proceed with updates...feel like building a house on top of the mud.

**Question 1 =>** Will having sample data on my initial install be a problem down the line?

**Question 2 =>** Is there a way to export the "changes" I've made and reinstall a clean instance of Magento, then upload those changes (mostly CMS pages, blocks, images, and product)?  I'm afraid of a full "migration" because I don't want the old "sample data" transferring to the new site as well.

Thanks in advance!